# rndc reload says zone was found in multiple views

Tags: dns, bind

```
$ sudo rndc reload 15.168.192.in-addr.arpa
rndc: 'reload' failed: multiple
zone '15.168.192.in-addr.arpa' was found in multiple views
```

It is true. I have the zone in multiple views, so I need to use the `[class [view]]` params of `rndc reload`.

What do I put for class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the answer in the manual. Class is just `IN` as in internet zone. BIND supports other things like hesoid and this field specifies that it is an internet zone.

```
sudo rndc reload 15.168.192.in-addr.arpa IN all
```

works where `all` is the name of my view.